# Problems with extracting table from PDF

Tags: pdf, web-scraping, scraperwiki, tabula

I know there is a few threads on this topic but none of their solutions seems to work for me. I have a table in a [PDF document](http://www.european-athletics.org/mm/Document/EventsMeetings/General/01/27/52/10/EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.pdf) from which I would like to be able to extract information. I can copy and paste the text into textedit and it is legible but not really useable. By this I mean all the text is readable but the data is all separated by spaces with no way to differentiate columns from spaces within text within a cell.

But whenever I try to use tools like tabula or scraper wiki the text extracted is garbage.

Is anyone able to give me any pointers as to how I might go about this?

Comment: Your PDF uses custom adhoc font encodings which it provides in the respective **Font** dictionary **Encoding** entries. It does not provide **ToUnicode** maps, though. There may be text extractors which cannot work based on that encoding entry alone. Probably newer releases will do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Python and Unix

In Python:

```
import urllib
# download pdf
testfile = urllib.URLopener()
testfile.retrieve('http://www.european-athletics.org/mm/Document/EventsMeetings/General/01/27/52/10/EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.pdf', 'test.pdf')
```

In Unix:

```
$ pdftotext -layout test.pdf
```

Snippet of output to test.txt:

`Lastname                     Firstname            Country    DOB          PB        SB
1500m Men
Rowe                         Brenton              AUT        17/08/1987
Vojta                        Andreas              AUT        09/06/1989   3:38.99   3:41.09
Khadiri                      Amine                CYP        20/11/1988   3:45.16   3:45.16
Friš                         Jan                  CZE        19/12/1995   3:43.76   3:43.76
Holuša                       Jakub                CZE        20/02/1988   3:38.79   3:41.54
Kocourek                     Milan                CZE        06/12/1987   3:43.97   3:43.97
Bueno                        Andreas              DEN        07/07/1988   3:42.78   3:42.78
Alcalá                       Marc                 ESP        07/11/1994   3:41.79   3:41.79
Mechaal                      Adel                 ESP        05/12/1990   3:38.30   3:38.30
Olmedo                       Manuel               ESP        17/05/1983   3:39.82   3:40.66
Ruíz                         Diego                ESP        05/02/1982   3:36.42   3:40.60
Kowal                        Yoann                FRA        28/05/1987   3:38.07   3:39.22
Grice                        Charlie              GBR        07/11/1993   3:39.44   3:39.44
O'Hare                       Chris                GBR        23/11/1990   3:37.25   3:40.42
Orth                         Florian              GER        24/07/1989   3:39.97   3:40.20
Tesfaye                      Homiyu               GER        23/06/1993   3:34.13   3:34.13
Kazi                         Tamás                HUN        16/05/1985   3:44.28   3:44.28
Mooney                       Danny                IRL        20/06/1988   3:42.69   3:42.69
Travers                      John                 IRL        16/03/1991   3:42.52   3:43.74
Bussotti Neves Junior        Joao Capistrano M.   ITA        10/05/1993   3:47.58   3:47.58
Jurkēvičs                    Dmitrijs             LAT        07/01/1987   3:45.95   3:45.95
Ingebrigtsen                 Henrik               NOR        24/02/1991   3:44.00
Ingebrigtsen                 Filip                NOR        20/04/1993
Krawczyk                     Szymon               POL        29/12/1988   3:41.64   3:41.64
Ostrowski                    Artur                POL        10/07/1988   3:41.36   3:41.36
 ebrowski                    Krzysztof            POL        09/07/1990   3:41.49   3:41.49
Smirnov                      Valentin             RUS        13/02/1986   3:37.55   3:38.74
Nava                         Goran                SRB        15/04/1981   3:40.65   3:44.49
Pelikán                      Jozef                SVK        29/07/1984   3:43.85   3:45.51
Ek                           Staffan              SWE        13/11/1991   3:43.54   3:43.54
Rogestedt                    Johan                SWE        27/01/1993   3:40.03   3:40.03
Özbilen                       lham Tanui          TUR        05/03/1990   3:34.76   3:38.05
Özdemir                      Ramazan              TUR        06/07/1991   3:44.35   3:44.35`

Comment: Thanks for your response. The output looks great and exactly what I need. However I am working on Mac. I have tried downloading a version of pdftotext for the mac from softpedia but this seems to produce an empty .txt file.

Comment: Not an expert on switching between operating systems, but you could try moving entirely to Unix OS. I believe pdftotext is a built in Unix command.

Comment: I've now managed to get hold of a Unix system to perform operation on but I'm still getting a bunch of symbols like this ÔÄöÔÄõÔÄúÔÄêÔÄíÔÄö when I open in textedit. Did you have to do anything with the encoding to get it to display nicely as above?

Comment: Try the enc option, described here http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_pdftote.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can also download a simple command line tool to deal with the PDF file you linked to. The run this command to extract the table(s) on the first page:

```
pdftotext     \
   -enc UTF-8 \
   -l 1       \
   -table     \
    EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.pdf \
    EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.txt
```

- **`-enc UTF-8`**: sets the text encoding so that the Ö, Ä, Ü and İ (as well as ö, ä, ü, ß, á, š, ē, í and č) characters in the text get correctly extracted.
- **`-l 1`**: tells the command to extract as the last page the page number 1.
- **`-table`**: this is the decisive parameter.

The command produces this output:

`EUROPEAN ATHLETICS INDOOR CHAMPIONSHIPS
                        PRAGUE / CZE, 6-8 MARCH 2015
                                   FINAL ENTRIES - MEN
Lastname                Firstname           Country     DOB         PB       SB
1500m Men
Rowe                    Brenton             AUT         17/08/1987
Vojta                   Andreas             AUT         09/06/1989  3:38.99  3:41.09
Khadiri                 Amine               CYP         20/11/1988  3:45.16  3:45.16
Friš                    Jan                 CZE         19/12/1995  3:43.76  3:43.76
Holuša                  Jakub               CZE         20/02/1988  3:38.79  3:41.54
Kocourek                Milan               CZE         06/12/1987  3:43.97  3:43.97
Bueno                   Andreas             DEN         07/07/1988  3:42.78  3:42.78
Alcalá                  Marc                ESP         07/11/1994  3:41.79  3:41.79
Mechaal                 Adel                ESP         05/12/1990  3:38.30  3:38.30
Olmedo                  Manuel              ESP         17/05/1983  3:39.82  3:40.66
Ruíz                    Diego               ESP         05/02/1982  3:36.42  3:40.60
Kowal                   Yoann               FRA         28/05/1987  3:38.07  3:39.22
Grice                   Charlie             GBR         07/11/1993  3:39.44  3:39.44
O'Hare                  Chris               GBR         23/11/1990  3:37.25  3:40.42
Orth                    Florian             GER         24/07/1989  3:39.97  3:40.20
Tesfaye                 Homiyu              GER         23/06/1993  3:34.13  3:34.13
Kazi                    Tamás               HUN         16/05/1985  3:44.28  3:44.28
Mooney                  Danny               IRL         20/06/1988  3:42.69  3:42.69
Travers                 John                IRL         16/03/1991  3:42.52  3:43.74
Bussotti Neves  Junior  Joao Capistrano M.  ITA         10/05/1993  3:47.58  3:47.58
Jurkēvičs               Dmitrijs            LAT         07/01/1987  3:45.95  3:45.95
Ingebrigtsen            Henrik              NOR         24/02/1991  3:44.00
Ingebrigtsen            Filip               NOR         20/04/1993
Krawczyk                Szymon              POL         29/12/1988  3:41.64  3:41.64
Ostrowski               Artur               POL         10/07/1988  3:41.36  3:41.36
Żebrowski               Krzysztof           POL         09/07/1990  3:41.49  3:41.49
Smirnov                 Valentin            RUS         13/02/1986  3:37.55  3:38.74
Nava                    Goran               SRB         15/04/1981  3:40.65  3:44.49
Pelikán                 Jozef               SVK         29/07/1984  3:43.85  3:45.51
Ek                      Staffan             SWE         13/11/1991  3:43.54  3:43.54
Rogestedt               Johan               SWE         27/01/1993  3:40.03  3:40.03
Özbilen                 İlham Tanui         TUR         05/03/1990  3:34.76  3:38.05
Özdemir                 Ramazan             TUR         06/07/1991  3:44.35  3:44.35
3000m Men
Rowe                    Brenton             AUT         17/08/1987
Vojta                   Andreas             AUT         09/06/1989  7:59.95  7:59.95`

### Note, however:

The ***`-table`*** parameter to the *pdftotext* command line tool is only available in the XPDF-version 3.04, which you can download here: **[www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/download.html)**. It is ***NOT*** (yet) available in Poppler's fork of *pdftotext* (latest version of which is 0.43.0).

If you only have Poppler's *pdftotext*, you'd have to use the ***`-layout`*** parameter (instead of ***`-table`***), which gives you a similarly good result for the PDF file in question:

```
pdftotext     \
   -enc UTF-8 \
   -l 1       \
   -layout    \
    EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.pdf \
    EICH-FinalEntriesforwebsite_Neutral.txt
```

However, I have seen PDFs where the result is much better with ***`-table`*** (and XPDF) than it is with ***`-layout`*** (and Poppler).

*(XPDF has the* `-layout` *parameter too -- so you can see the difference if you try both.)*